# Undefined variable in View?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Im having a little problem that i dont understand..

My Controller:

```
<?php

class SearchController extends BaseController{

    public function postSearch(){

        $course = Input::get('course_category');

        if(empty($course)){

            return Redirect::route('search')
            ->with('global','<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" align="center">Du måste välja kurs och universitet!</div>');

        }else{

            $courses = Posts::where('course_category','LIKE','%'.$course.'%')->get();

            return View::make('search')
                            ->with('course_category',$courses)
                            ->with('courses',$courses);
        }

    }
}
```

My View:

```
@extends('layout.main')
@section('content')



{{Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'route' =>array('post-search')))}}

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('course_category','Språk')}}
    {{Form::select('course_category',array(
        ''              =>'-Choose--',
        'php'            => 'PHP',
        'javascript'     =>'Javascript',
        'java'           =>'Java',
        'C#'             =>'C#',
        'html'           =>'HTML',
        'css'            =>'CSS',
        '.net'           =>'.NET',
        'jquery'         =>'jQuery',
        'ajax'           =>'Ajax'

    ))}}
</div>

    {{Form::submit('Sök',array('class'=>'btn btn-info'))}}

    {{Form::token()}}

{{Form::close()}}
```

```
@if($courses->count())

    @foreach($courses as $c)

        <p>{{$c->title}}</p>

    @endforeach

@endif

@stop
```

This is the error that my View search is throwing:

> ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
>   Undefined variable: courses (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/LaraBoost/app/views/search.blade.php)

How is it possible that the $courses variable in the view is undefined when i pass it to the View from the Controller?

What did i  miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, you have problem in your controller code, the logic doesn't seem right but to overcome the view problem you may try something like this:

```
@if(isset($courses) && $courses->count())
    //...
@endif
```

Since `$courses` is undefined then it's not being sent. If you try this instead

```
@if(isset($courses) && $courses->count())
    //...
@else
    {{'No Courses'}}
@endif
```

You'll get the idea and it'll let you understand what you are doing.

Comment: it works!Thank you! :) so i need to se if the variable isset and if its any records of it in the DB? right? Can you please give a tip o the logic i my controller? I want the i statement to take place when the user havent selected anything from the list and clicks search. Thats why i use if(empty($courser))....

Comment: Probably the redirect is taking place, check for `$course_category` in the view.